# Request fails or function cannot find element, in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a part of the parser, but when it works, an error occurs that I cannot figure out how to solve.
The parser works like this - first, it collects all links from external pages to internal pages with resume and collects them in a list. Having collected all the links, it starts bypassing them and collects data from them.
The problem arises when parsing resume pages.

```
import scrapy
import re
import csv
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

list_link = []
list_link_page = []

class hh(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hh'
    allowed_domains = ["krasnoyarsk.hh.ru"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        extractor = LinkExtractor(allow_domains='krasnoyarsk.hh.ru') 
        links = extractor.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            link = str(link.url)
            append_link = re.search(re.escape('https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resume/') + '.*', link)
            if append_link: 
                list_link.append(append_link.group())

        for link in links:
            link = str(link.url)
            append_page_link = re.search(re.escape('https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham?page=') + '.*', link)
            if len(list_link_page) < 10:
                if append_page_link:
                    list_link_page.append(append_page_link.group())
            else:
                break
            
        for link in list_link_page:
            if link == response.url:
                list_link_page.remove(link)            
            else:
                next_page = response.urljoin(link)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

        if response.url == list_link_page[-1]:
            for page in list_link_page:
                request = response.urljoin(page)
                return scrapy.Request(request, callback=self.ParsingResume)

    def ParsingResume(self, response):

        gender = response.css('span.resume-block__salary').getall()
        print(gender)
        return
```

Error - Terminal(Linux):

```
2020-11-14 22:51:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.0 started (bot: hh)
2020-11-14 22:51:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.1.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) - [GCC 7.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-5.4.0-48-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
2020-11-14 22:51:27 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-11-14 22:51:27 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'hh',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'hh.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['hh.spiders']}
2020-11-14 22:51:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 414a5184ce320dc3
2020-11-14 22:51:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-11-14 22:51:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-11-14 22:51:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-11-14 22:51:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-11-14 22:51:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-11-14 22:51:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-14 22:51:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6026
2020-11-14 22:51:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham> (referer: None)
2020-11-14 22:51:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham?page=1> (referer: https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham)
2020-11-14 22:51:31 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py:149: UserWarning: The "hh.parse" method is a generator and includes a "return" statement with a value different than None. This could lead to unexpected behaviour. Please see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement for details about the semantics of the "return" statement within generators
  warn_on_generator_with_return_value(spider, callback)

2020-11-14 22:51:32 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham?page=3> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2020-11-14 22:51:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham?page=249> (referer: https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham)
2020-11-14 22:51:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham?page=4> (referer: https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham)
2020-11-14 22:51:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham?page=0> (referer: https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham?page=1)
2020-11-14 22:51:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham?page=3> (referer: https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham)
2020-11-14 22:51:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham?page=2> (referer: https://krasnoyarsk.hh.ru/resumes/menedzher_po_prodazham)
2020-11-14 22:51:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-11-14 22:51:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 4030,
 'downloader/request_count': 7,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 7,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1397853,
 'downloader/response_count': 7,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 7,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 35,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 11.247191,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 14, 15, 51, 39, 905080),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'memusage/max': 53489664,
 'memusage/startup': 53489664,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 7,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 7,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 7,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 7,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 7,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 14, 15, 51, 28, 657889)}
2020-11-14 22:51:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain your logic a bit? Why you simply don't get all resume links like this:

```
for resume_url in response.xpath('//a[@class="resume-search-item__name"]/@href').getall():
    yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(resume_url), callback=self.ParsingResume)
```